# Convergence of imaginary sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Does this sequence converge?

$a_n = \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{n-i}{n}\right)^n+\left(\dfrac{1+i}{2}\right)^n}{i+\left(\dfrac{1+i\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^n}$

I tried to look at the real part and the imaginary part separately but i don't get there with all the fractions.

Comment: Are you sure of the number in the denominator?

Comment: it should be $(\frac{n-i}{n})$ thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Observe that

$$\left|\frac12+\frac i{\sqrt2}\right|=\sqrt{\frac14+\frac12}=\frac{\sqrt3}2<1\implies\left(\frac12+\frac i{\sqrt2}\right)^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

and in similar manner:

$$\left(\frac{n-i}n\right)^n=\left(1-\frac in\right)^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e^{-i}$$

$$\left|\frac{1+i}2\right|=\sqrt{\frac14+\frac14}=\frac1{\sqrt2}<1\implies\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

so finally:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{n-i}{n}\right)^n+\left(\dfrac{1+i}{2}\right)^n}{i+\left(\dfrac{1+i\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^n}=\frac{e^{-i}+0}{i+0}=\frac1{ie^i}$$